# Non-deterministic parameters to custom function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a problem with Google Spreadsheets: I create a custom function using the Script Editor and it only runs OK if the parameters I pass are known (constant) values.

If the parameters are non-deterministic functions, I get the `Thinking...` text and the evaluation is never completed.

By non-deterministic functions, I mean functions whose result may differ every time it's called (for example: `Rand()`, `Now()`).

To illustrate this, I have two examples:

#### 1. Function to add 1 to a number

Here's the code:

```
function plusOne(i) {
  return i + 1;
}
```

As expected, if I enter `=plusOne(5)` in a cell, I get the result `6`.

However, if I enter `=plusOne(rand())` I expect to get a random result between 1 and 2 (as the documentation states that `rand()` *"Returns a random number between 0 and 1"*)

The formula `=plusOne(rand())` never finishes evaluation and the cell remains in the *"Thinking..."* state.

#### 2. Function to get the Month from a Date

```
function gimmeMonth(date) {
  return date.getMonth() + 1;
}
```

Again, if I call this with a constant parameter it works fine. For example, if I enter `2012-08-31` in cell `A1`, the formula `=gimmeMonth(A1)` returns the expected result `8`.

However, `=gimmeMonth(now())` never gets evaluated, although the builtin `month()` function works fine in this case (`=month(now())` returns the expected result).

#### Why I need this

I need to be able to add a non-deterministic parameter in my custom function calls in order to [avoid cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060267/390819).

Has anyone else had this problem? Anyone managed to solve it?

Comment: Interesting! If I put `=rand()` in `A1` and `=plusOne(A1)` in `A2`, the number in `A1` changes about every 5 seconds. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: @WilliamJackson I noticed that every time a formula is evaluated, all non-deterministic functions are re-evaluated as well. Perhaps something fails and it retries every 5 seconds, triggering the `rand()` to yield a new value. Anyway, it's really weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made some research and it seems like an old problem, even from old MS Excel versions.

I think the best/easiest way is to create your own randomization function. This way random value won't be regenerated. You use it the same way as before `=plusOne(myRandom())`

```
function plusOne(i) {
  return i + 1;
}

function myRandom() {
  # Some function
  return Math.random();
}
```

You could also shorten it `=myRandom()`

```
function myRandom() {
  # Some function
  return Math.random() + 1;
}
```